# How to move navigation bar to the right in landscape mode?

Tags: settings, 9.0-pie, google-pixel-2, navigation-bar

I just got a Pixel 2, running Android 9. I've noticed that when I turn my phone landscape, the soft keys always go to the "bottom" of the phone, which is sometimes on the left of the screen. I'm used to the behavior of the soft keys orienting themselves on the right side of the landscape, no matter which way is up, like on Android 7 (I was using a Nexus 5 before this). It's hard for me to use my left hand on the keys as I am not used to it, and I'm used to swiping in from the right to bring them up as well.

Is there a way to adjust this setting?

Comment: This is something I've accomplished via modifying the source code, but frankly I'm not sure if it can be done in another way...

Comment: @AndyYan is it possible for you to teach me how to do this? I've been meaning to learn small UI tweaks for a while (like having a battery bar for Bluetooth devices) but never really got around to it. I have experience in programming android apps in Java, as well as C++ and Kotlin

Comment: Can you build the ROM you're running in the first place? If you're using the stock ROM then the patch won't work (as said, I work on the source), and some sort of decompiling/recompiling needs to be done, but I don't know of a way to reliably decompile/recompile Pie stuff as of yet.

Comment: Alright, I'll look into learning to build my own ROM first then

Comment: In the meantime I'll try to figure out `apktool` on Pie, if that works then I might have an answer for you :) Just don't expect it to come soon.